# React Download JS PDF file download error

Tags: reactjs, express, pdf, download, multer

I am trying to download a file I stored in my server. I can upload the file without any error. But when I download the file, as in the code below, I can download the file but the `catch` block is running as well. It catches the below error, but the file is downloading.

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

This error only occurs in Edge and Chrome. When I do this in FireFox I don't get any error. Here is my code:

```js
// This is my download function which run when I click the download button in REACT
const handleResumeDownload = async () => {
  const resumeName = props.applicationDetails.resumeName;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(${ BACKEND_URL } / resume / ${ props.jobId } / ${ props.userId }, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
    console.log("response", response);
    download(response.data, "Resume", "application/pdf");
    // File even downloads here but then goes to catch block
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

// Server side call back function of the above api call
const downloadResume = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.set({
      'Content-Type': "application/pdf"
    });
    const resumeName = req.params.jobId + "--" + req.params.userId + ".pdf";
    const resumePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', "resumes", resumeName);
    res.sendFile(resumePath);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: "Error while downloading file. Please try again later."
    });
  }
}
```